# Multiple concurrent cisco VPN client connections

Tags: vpn, cisco-vpn-client

I have the requirement where a piece of software that dials into the tax office uses cisco vpn client, but I also need my accountant to VPN to my office - requiring the cisco vpn client to make two concurrent connections.

Does anyone know if this is possible? I realise its likely that the network will have to be different but just wondering if there is any way to do this or not?

Comment: Are you trying to do two OUTBOUND connections from your computer, or are the two connections inbound to the office?  Tell us more about the Cisco config, ie is it an ASA or PIX?  Cisco Anywhere or something different?

Comment: Two outbound VPN connections from one PC to two different ASA's from two different companies

Answer (score 2):

Had exactly the same problem, as Cisco only allows one connection per machine.  Ended up installing Cisco on the base machine and also a virtual machine on the base machine, thereby allowing a different connection on each simultaneously.

Not ideal, but it does the job.  You could also use shared folders if the work you are doing needs to be shared between machines.

Answer (score -1):

See my answer to a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/547507/stop-windows-7-from-clobbering-one-vpn-when-connecting-to-a-second/547663#547663).

Having concurrent connections is not only doable; but rather simple to achieve. You'll just need to keep control of your routes, the default route in particular; which most VPN software vendors don't seem to think we lowly users have a need to do.

Comment: The difference I think is that you have done this with microsoft VPN and I'm doing it with Cisco VPN, but this insight may offer assistance in some way so thanks regardless

Comment: I use it pretty much exclusively with Cisco VPNs presently; my current primary endpoint is a Cisco Pix 5501. The solution I linked to is fairly generic; it doesn't matter which VPN software you use, routing is routing. And I'm glad if it's even just a little useful to you. However I do have to ensure that the --enable-1des switch is active for my particular setup.

Comment: Ill have a chop at it and let you know ;)