# How can I print wirelessly to my local printer when I use VPN?

Tags: vpn, printing, cisco-vpn-client

From the Googling I've done, this doesn't seem to be possible (or not easily achievable). Nevertheless, is it possible to print to my local (home) wireless printer when I'm connected to my office's VPN? I am using Cisco's VPN Client.

Comment: If the VPN policy is set to block local network connections then it is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the configuration of your VPN.

If it is set to redirect **all** traffic to the other (work) network; then no.
All traffic is all traffic, including any traffic you wanted routed to a local printer.

If you have a split tunnel where you only route traffic for the work IP range over the VPN tunnel then you can access both locations. This is often disabled for security reasons.

(The cisco VPN client supports both, as well as locking it down to the safe mode.

Comment: How can I tell if the VPN config is set to redirect all traffic or not?

Comment: SSeveral ways: 1) Look in the VPN clients configuration.  2) print the routing tables before and after starting the VPN client. or 3) ping a device on you local network which is not your default gateway. Then start the VPN. If ping starts to return timeouts then split tunneling is not used.

Comment: Some useful links: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling ---  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisco_Systems_VPN_Client  --- The answers on https://supportforums.cisco.com/thread/2105545  --- And the workaround in http://forums.speedguide.net/showthread.php?209167-Cisco-VPN-client-connects-but-restricts-LAN-access-even-when-option-is-ENABLED

Answer (score 0):

This is a client-side setting. See my answer to a similar post [here](https://superuser.com/questions/547507/stop-windows-7-from-clobbering-one-vpn-when-connecting-to-a-second/547663#547663) for how to change the setting in Windows. If you are using linux, it's even simpler. but uses the same general principle.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an pretty old question but I'm going to answer since it might still save others some trouble. I am a remote employee at a customer site using BIG-IP Edge Client to connect to the home office with VPN. I'd been spending a lot of time disconnecting and reconnecting from the VPN to accomplish daily print jobs. Following web advice, I attempted to set up persistent routes to the printer, enable split tunneling, creating a scheduled task that added a route whenever a VPN connection was made, etc.  None of it worked. Finally, I set up remote printing on my Epson printer via Epson Connect. Now I just select the "Epson Remote Print" printer while connected to VPN and my documents print to my local printer over an Internet connection. Many network enabled printers have Internet printing so it's an easy solution to wirelessly print to the local printer while connected over VPN.