# Forwarding VPN connection

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, cisco-vpn-client

Is it possible to forward a VPN connection from one machine to another (like ssh port forwarding maybe)?

This way I can use two VPN connections at the same time from one screen.

Any network guru out there? Thanks!

Comment: Which kind of VPN are you using? Where do you want to apply the connection forwarding?

Comment: Possible duplicate, if you only want to forward it, because you want to have two vpn-connection at the same time: http://superuser.com/questions/547507/stop-windows-7-from-clobbering-one-vpn-when-connecting-to-a-second?lq=1

Comment: Chris: yes that's the intention (being able to use two VPN connections at the same time). But the linked question has only a solution for Windows 7. I guess same principles can be applied to OS X.

For now I'm happy to be able to use two VNCs via a non-direct solution posted below. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but this answered my need of using two VNCs from two VPN connections.

Just port forward VNC on the machine behind VPN (A) to a remote VPN-connected machine (B), and then do VNC on the local (C) to machine B. One VNC connection being tunneled twice!