# Is there any chance to have multiple VPN connections using Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client?

Tags: networking, vpn, cisco-vpn-client

I googled so much but I haven't found anything about having multiple connections using Cisco AnyConnect. [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/547507/stop-windows-7-from-clobbering-one-vpn-when-connecting-to-a-second/547663#547663) is the answer about configuring already connected VPNs but how to make Client connect to another VPN when it's already connected to some VPN?

So is there any way? If it exists then how it should be configured? I work with 3 clients and all of them use Cisco AnyConnect so every time I should disconnect and then connect to another VPN. It really annoys.

Is it possible, for example, to create virtual adapter for every connection and join VPN using it?